# Shift-Insert to paste in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, paste

Any clue how to get Shift-Insert to paste in OS X using a windows keyboard?

I use the mouse on the left side so command-v is makes me switch back and forth a lot. I have had no luck with any of my searches.

Comment: Your answer can be found in [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/how-can-i-reassign-the-copy-paste-keyboard-shortcuts) thread.

Comment: Or this one: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/how-can-i-reassign-the-copy-paste-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately none of those suggestions work on that page.

Comment: Far as I can tell, most answers are out of date and don't work with Mojave. Best bet seems to be using Karabiner Elements app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was finally able to get this to work using Karabiner-Elements - https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html

I created a "Complex Modifications" to allow this by adding this modifier to one of the json files:

```
    {
  "description": "PC-Style Shift-Insert Paste",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "insert",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": [
            "shift"
          ],
          "optional": [
            "any"
          ]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "v",
          "modifiers": [
            "left_command"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "conditions": [
        {
          "type": "frontmost_application_unless",
          "bundle_identifiers": [
            "^com\\.microsoft\\.rdc$",
            "^com\\.microsoft\\.rdc\\.mac$",
            "^com\\.microsoft\\.rdc\\.macos$",
            "^com\\.microsoft\\.rdc\\.osx\\.beta$",
            "^net\\.sf\\.cord$",
            "^com\\.thinomenon\\.RemoteDesktopConnection$",
            "^com\\.itap-mobile\\.qmote$",
            "^com\\.nulana\\.remotixmac$",
            "^com\\.p5sys\\.jump\\.mac\\.viewer$",
            "^com\\.p5sys\\.jump\\.mac\\.viewer\\.web$",
            "^com\\.teamviewer\\.TeamViewer$",
            "^com\\.vmware\\.horizon$",
            "^com\\.2X\\.Client\\.Mac$",
            "^com\\.vmware\\.fusion$",
            "^com\\.vmware\\.horizon$",
            "^com\\.vmware\\.view$",
            "^com\\.parallels\\.desktop$",
            "^com\\.parallels\\.vm$",
            "^com\\.parallels\\.desktop\\.console$",
            "^org\\.virtualbox\\.app\\.VirtualBoxVM$",
            "^com\\.vmware\\.proxyApp\\.",
            "^com\\.parallels\\.winapp\\.",
            "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
            "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
            "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
            "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
            "^io\\.alacritty$",
            "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: How to and where to include this JSON is explained here https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1225

Answer (score 12):

Though I have Mac I spend most of the time on a Linux virtual machine.

I really need Shift-Insert to access the selections clipboard.

So I remapped on my linux machine F9 which I rarely use to behave like Insert.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 75 = Insert Insert Insert"
```

Put this in a file that is being load in your window manager startup

So now I can use Shift-F9 to insert.

Comment: too bad Yosemite doesn't user X11.. for performance, I'm not fond of installing X11 just to get a key. There must be a way to remap a key on Yosemite with xmodmap..

Answer (score 11):

Being primarly a Linux guy, I use the Shift-Ins method mostly in the terminal, where Ctrl-V doesn't always work. **iTerm2** lets you remap keys.

`Preferences -> Keys -> Key Mappings -> +`

Then select Paste from the Action list, and click on the Keyboard Shortcut and press Shift-Ins. It will show up as Shift-Help.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac paste works with cmd + v(same as ctrl + v as in Windows)

But this shortcut doesn't work for Linux Bash shell, such as to paste to file being edited with vi editor.

Did some search, tried out some short cuts and found out ctrl + shift + v works for my Mac for Linux command line shell or for vi editor properly same as that of shift + insert in windows or Linux

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set up working <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>/<kbd>Delete</kbd> shortcuts for Copy, Cut and Paste using Keyboard Maestro, but had a really difficult time coming to that conclusion. I even managed to set up a right hand undo (which Windows doesn't have afaik).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).